# How to get index's value from $_POST using foreach

Tags: php

I want to know the correct code to detect only numerical $_POST fields coming from the form.

Please correct my code.

```
foreach ($_POST as $vals) {
  if (is_numeric($vals)) {
    if (is_numeric($vals[$i]) && ($vals[$i]!="0")) {
    //do something
  } 
}
```

Comment: What's not working here?  Where is `$i` coming from?  This code looks fine, just remove the 2nd `if` statement.

Comment: I want to keep only numerical form fields coming from $_POST. but it's bringing everything including the numerical values inside the fields

Comment: `foreach ($_POST as $key=>$vals)` and then `if(is_numeric($key))`

Answer (score 5):

```
$_POST = array_filter($_POST, "is_numeric");
```

The above will remove all non-numeric array items.

```
foreach (array_filter($_POST, "is_numeric") as $key => $val)
{   
    // do something
    echo "$key is equal to $val which is numeric.";  
}
```

**Update:**

If you only want those like $_POST[1], $_POST[2], etc..

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $vals){
    if (is_numeric($key)){
      //do something
    }   
}
```

Comment: it's bringing the values , I want to compare the field names . If they are numeric then proceed.

Comment: Updated the above. Just do the foreach on the array_filter. If that's not what you mean, could you provide some psuedocode?

Comment: @sixeightzero: I think he wants to remove `$_POST['name']`, but keep `$_POST['12']`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
{   
  if (is_numeric($key))
  {
    // do something
  }   
}
```

Comment: Hi des, it's bringing the results inside the fields, i want only the numerical  fields..

Comment: so you want numerical keys not values... let me then correct my answer

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $vals){
     //this is read: $_POST[$key]=$value   
     if (is_numeric($vals) && ($vals!="0")){
          //do something
     }   
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST)){
   foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
       if(is_numeric($key)){
          echo $value;
       }
   }
}
```

Compare the keys

Answer (score 0):

The following code with `isset()` trying to work on an array is invalid.

```
if(isset($_POST)){   //isset() only works on variables and array elements.
   foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
       if(is_numeric($key)){
          echo $value;
       }
   }
```

---

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
{   
  if (is_numeric($key))
  {
    // do something
  }   
}
```

Better, but now foreach will make a copy of $_POST and put in in memory for the duration of the loop (Programming PHP: Ch. 6, p. 128-129). I hope buffer overflows or out of memory errors don't jump up and bite you. :-)

---

Perhaps it would be wiser to determine some facts about $_POST with is_array(), empty(), count() and others before getting started, such as ...

```
if(is_array($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
{
    if(count($_POST) === count($arrayOfExpectedControlNames))
    {   
        //Where the the values for the $postKeys have already been validated some...

        if(in_array($arrayOfExpectedControlNames, $postKeys))
        {
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)  //If you insist on using foreach.
            {   
                if (is_numeric($key))
                {
                   // do something
                }
                else
                {
                   //Alright, already. Enough!
                }   
            }
        }
        else
        {
             //Someone is pulling your leg!
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Definitely a sham!
    }
}
else
{
    //It's a sham!
}
```

Still, the `$val` values need some validation, but I'm sure you are up on that.

Comment: `//isset() only works on variables and array elements` – that’s a nonsense statement in this context, `$_POST` _is_ a variable. The _problem_ is that it is _always_ set, but might be empty, which is why using `isset` on it to check whether the request method was POST is pointless. `empty` will work though, or using `count`.

Comment: My friend, `$_POST` is an array in this context (be it a superglobal). My statement makes good sense. The PHP language construct `isset()` is not meant to work on arrays, only _variables_ and _array elements_. Thus, whatever your prior reasoning, it is not valid to use `isset()` on `$_POST`. [PHP Manual: isset()](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)